# Are .JSON and сhunk .js in Next.js files important for Googlebot to render page correctly?

Tags: googlebot, search-engine-indexing, google-index, next.js

I have a problem with Googlebot indexing my website. He scans a lot of JSON [image] and chunks .js [image] files instead of scanning. HTML files. These unnecessary files reduce the crawl budget of my website. So the question is can I block them in robots.txt or in another way? And will it hurt page rendering for Googlebot and internal link following? Maybe somebody has experience with tech SEO using next.js. It's common problem , but i can't find answer.

Comment: How many files is "a lot"?  Unless it is several times the number of HTML pages you have, I wouldn't worry about it. Most sites are not limited by Googlebot's crawl budget.

Comment: Part of the problem might be the string of hex near the end of those file names.  You probably have that there for cache-busting purposes.  Is that true?  How is the hex generated and how often is it updated?

Comment: See - https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137447/should-i-block-the-next-directory-in-a-site-using-next-js-with-robots-txt